# Is it possible to run react-scripts start from within another directory that has a public folder but not a package.json file?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, react-scripts

yarn version: `1.22.19`

`package.json` file in the `myapp` dir:

```
"main": "server/index.js",
...
"dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.2.2",
    ...
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.5",
    ...
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    ...
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    ...
}
```

Here's my file structure:

```
myapp
 | -- client
 |     | -- build
 |     | -- public
 |     | -- src
 |
 | -- mailer
 |     | -- index.js
 |     
 | -- node_modules
 |
 | -- server
 |     | -- index.js
 |
 | -- package.json
 | -- yarn.lock
```

Is this even a thing I can do?

Can I use `yarn` -- possibly in conjunction with `react-scripts` -- to start all three folders: `client`, `mailer`, and `server` from within the `myapp` folder, assuming I changed my terminal directory (`cd`) to `myapp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're going for a monorepo architecture with the single node_modules at the root level. However, you'll still want a package.json  for your `client` and `mailer` React apps.

With Yarn workspaces, you can keep all `node_modules` installed at the root level (except ones that are unique to `/client` or `/mailer`, their unique `node_modules` will be installed in their respective directories. This way you still maintain each React app's `package.json` which contains `react-scripts` as normal.

Then in your root-level `package.json`, you can start all 3 apps using `yarn dev`. See `scripts` below:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./server/index.js",
  "start-client": "cd ./client && yarn start",
  "start-mailer": "cd ./mailer && yarn start",
  "start-app": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn start\" \"yarn start-client\" \"yarn start-mailer\"",
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=development yarn start-app"
},
```

- Yarn 1 Workspaces: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/
- Yarn 2 Workspaces: https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces

I recommend using [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/docs/getting-started) which uses Yarn under the hood and makes things easier to understand and deal with at a high level.

While there may be a way to hack an app into doing this without package.json files, I don't think it's the right approach if you're focused on a monorepo / single node_modules at root.